# Faster RCNN (caffe) Joint Learning: Out of Memory with dedicated memory 5376 MB (changed batch sizes and no.of RPN proposals) what else?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have worked with the alternative optimization matlab code before, currently I am trying to get joint learning running. I am able to run the test demo with my GPU Tesla 2070. For training, I have set all the batch sizes to 1:

```
__C.TRAIN.IMS_PER_BATCH = 1
__C.TRAIN.BATCH_SIZE = 1
__C.TRAIN.RPN_BATCHSIZE = 1
```

(updated yaml to 1 as well since it was overridden)

But I still have the error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0) out of memory.

I have tried to experiment with lowering the number of proposals. (the originals are below:)

train:
Number of top scoring boxes to keep before apply NMS to RPN proposals

```
C.TRAIN.RPN_PRE_NMS_TOP_N = 12000
```

Number of top scoring boxes to keep after applying NMS to RPN proposals

```
C.TRAIN.RPN_POST_NMS_TOP_N = 2000
```

test:
Number of top scoring boxes to keep before apply NMS to RPN proposals

```
C.TEST.RPN_PRE_NMS_TOP_N = 6000
```

Number of top scoring boxes to keep after applying NMS to RPN proposals

```
C.TEST.RPN_POST_NMS_TOP_N = 300
```

I tried as low as pre: 100 post:50 for sanity check.

And I still am not able to run without the out of memory problem. What am I missing here?? I have a Tesla 5376 MB dedicated memory and I use the Tesla only for this (have a separate GPU for my screen) I am positive about reading 5376 MB should be enough by an author himself.

Thanks.

Comment: I am talking about the faster rcnn that uses caffe, should have stated in the headline